# Gauge transformation of an adjoint left-handed Weyl spinor in $\rm SU(2)$ fundamental representation

Tags: field-theory, gauge-theory, spinors, yang-mills, dirac-matrices

I have a left-handed Weyl spinor field $\Psi_L$ in the fundamental representation of the $\rm SU(2)$ gauge group, which transforms $\Psi_{L,i} \rightarrow \Psi_{L,i} + i\theta^at_{ij}^a\Psi_{L,j}$.

According to the professor, the adjoint will transform as $\overline{\Psi}_{L,i} \rightarrow \overline{\Psi}_{L,i} - i\theta^a\overline{\Psi}_{L,j}t_{ji}^a$ but I can't obtain the same result.

I'm doing the following to get the adjoint:

$\Psi^{*}_{L,i} \rightarrow \Psi^{*}_{L,i} - i\theta^a\Psi_{L,j}(t_{ji}^*)^a$, then
$$\Psi^{*}_{L,i}(\gamma^0)_{ik} \rightarrow \Psi^{*}_{L,i}(\gamma^0)_{ik} - i\theta^a\Psi_{L,j}(t_{ji}^*)^a(\gamma^0)_{ik}.$$ Since $t^a$ are the generators of $\rm SU(2)$, $t^a = \frac{1}{2}\sigma^a$, with $\sigma^a$ the Pauli matrices, they are hermitian. Therefore,
$$\Psi^{*}_{L,i}(\gamma^0)_{ik} \rightarrow \Psi^{*}_{L,i}(\gamma^0)_{ik} - i\theta^a\Psi_{L,j}t_{ij}^a(\gamma^0)_{ik}.$$ I'm a bit confused about how to get to the correct result.

I'm also confused about the size of $\gamma^0$, given that $i, j, k \in \{1, 2\}$ and $\gamma^{\mu}$ size is 4x4.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You are mixing up $\rm SU(2)$ indices and Dirac indices.

Comment: How so? Don't Weyl spinors have 2 components? Thanks!

Comment: The left-handed field $\psi_L =\frac{1-\gamma_5}{2} \psi$ has still four Dirac indices, it is the projection operator $P_L = \frac{1-\gamma_5}{2}$ that reduces the number of degrees of freedom. As is obvious from your use of $\gamma^0$ you are not using two-component spinor notation (which you could do in principle, but it is not necessary). In any case, the $4$ Dirac indices have nothing to do with the $2$ indices of the $\rm SU(2)$ gauge group.

Comment: aah, I understand, so that has the effect that $\gamma^0$ and t^a commute? Thanks a lot

Comment: You never wrote down the spinor indices: you suppressed them as most people do, because there is little possibility of confusion of apples with oranges. You certainly should not label spinors and gamma matrices with weak isospin indices!

Comment: @zequi Yes, $\gamma^0$ and $t^a$ live in different spaces.

Comment: Thank you both!